# Permission denied error given for IE webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to run my automation scripts on ie11 but i am getting permission denied error for ie 11 webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Ie(IEDriverManager().install())
```

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\Users\Dell\.wdm\IEDriverServer\3.141.59\x64\IEDriverServer.exe'

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also download the IE Drivers based on your OS: [Windows 32 bit driver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip) or [Windows 64 bit driver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0.zip), then extract the zip and copy IEDriverServer.exe file to some location where the user has right to access it. Then using the following code to open an IE browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Ie("D:\\Downloads\\webdriver\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

The user you are running as does not have permissions to write files to the `C:\Users\Dell\.wdm` directory, or its sub directories.

You'll need to allow your user to have write access to this directory, or try to have `IEDriverManager().install()` use a directory your user can write to.

Comment: This should nail the OP